# Exporting Tinkergraph SubGraph to File using Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

Using JanusGraph and Gremlin, I have a graph export requirement which seems to be failing. From the Gremlin console, I am able to export my small graph with:
 `g.io('sample.json').write().iterate()` successfully. `g` is `==>graphtraversalsource[standardjanusgraph[berkeleyje:/var/lib/janusgraph/data], standard]`

Now I want to do the same with a subgraph, so from the gremlin console, I am generating a tingergraph as shown below:

```
gremlin> sn_graph = g.V().hasLabel('rule').repeat(bothE().subgraph('sample').otherV()).times(3).cap('sample').next()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:285 edges:276]
gremlin> sg = sn_graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:285 edges:276], standard]
gremlin> sg.io('/tmp/sample.json').write().iterate()
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.console.RemoteException
```

I was hoping that I will be able to export my subgraph to file, the same way I was able to export my original graph `g`. But I keep running to an exception. The only difference I feel is that one is based on berkeleyje and the other is tinkergraph.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:158)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier.getInVertexId(RelationIdentifier.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:688)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeWithType(BeanSerializerBase.java:604)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONUtil.writeWithType(GraphSONUtil.java:51)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.star.StarGraphGraphSONSerializerV2d0.ser(StarGraphGraphSONSerializerV2d0.java:89)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.star.StarGraphGraphSONSerializerV2d0.serializeWithType(StarGraphGraphSONSerializerV2d0.java:65)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.star.StarGraphGraphSONSerializerV2d0.serializeWithType(StarGraphGraphSONSerializerV2d0.java:48)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.impl.TypeWrappedSerializer.serialize(TypeWrappedSerializer.java:32)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3905)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:3176)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONWriter.writeVertex(GraphSONWriter.java:82)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONWriter.writeVertices(GraphSONWriter.java:110)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONWriter.writeGraph(GraphSONWriter.java:71)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.sideEffect.IoStep.write(IoStep.java:121)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.sideEffect.IoStep.processNextStart(IoStep.java:112)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:143)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:50)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.filter.FilterStep.processNextStart(FilterStep.java:37)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:128)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:38)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Traversal.iterate(Traversal.java:203)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversal.iterate(GraphTraversal.java:2862)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversal$Admin.iterate(GraphTraversal.java:187)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal.iterate(DefaultGraphTraversal.java:48)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversal$Admin$iterate.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:119)
    at Script205.run(Script205.groovy:1)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:674)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:376)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.lambda$eval$0(GremlinExecutor.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I can't seem to figure out what I am missing here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you ellided the full stack trace - could you include all of it please?

Comment: Hi Stephen. Thank you for looking in. I've updated with the question with the full stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your TinkerGraph contains JanusGraph identifiers - `RelationIdentifier` - and GraphSON does not know how to serialize that. You need to provide the JanusGraph GraphSON serializers as follows as discussed [here](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/java/articles/janusgraph-tips-and-tricks-pt-2/):

```
file = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/sample.json")
mapper = GraphSONMapper.build().addCustomModule(org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.io.graphson.JanusGraphSONModuleV2d0.getInstance()).create()
writer = GraphSONWriter.build().mapper(mapper).create()
writer.writeGraph(file, sg)
```

The above approach uses `GraphSONWriter` directly, but you can also hand it to the `io()` step since you are sending scripts through Gremlin Console:

```
sg.io('/tmp/sample.json').
     with(IO.registry, JanusGraphIoRegistry.getInstance()).
   write().iterate()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen. I was able to export using GraphSONWriter. I though about serialization issues, but because I was able to export the full graph without trouble, did not think it would be an issue with subgraphs. Is this because my initial g was an instance of `graphtraversalsource[standardjanusgraph..]` and the subgraph was instance of TinkerGraph?

Comment: Also, for the second option, is it `by` or `with`? I had trouble with both
`gremlin>org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.io.graphson.JanusGraphSONModuleV2d0.getInstance()
==>org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.io.graphson.JanusGraphSONModuleV2d0@4f947862
gremlin> sg.io('/tmp/sample2.json').with(IO.registry,  org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.io.graphson.JanusGraphSONModuleV2d0.getInstance()).write().iterate()
ClassNotFoundException JanusGraphSONModuleV2d0
`
So the console is able to find `JanusGraphSONModuleV2d0`, but not when I sending it as part of the IO function.

Comment: Your initial graph was JanusGraph so your TinkerGraph contains JanusGraph identifiers for graph elements like vertices/edges. As a result, you need to tell GraphSON how to deal with those. I've updated my answer - I screwed up the second code example